# Can you have a Microsoft DNS server send zone updates to a DNS server running on a nonstandard port?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible to make a Microsoft DNS server send zone update notifications to a BIND DNS server running on a nonstandard port, e.g. `5353`?

### Background

I've inherited some legacy infrastructure where a BIND DNS server is listening on two separate ports, with a different port being used for different zones.

- EXAMPLE.COM is listening on the standard port 53.
- EXAMPLE.NET is listening on a decidedly non-standard port 5353.

I'm told this was to support a filtering appliance that is no longer in use, the specific whytos and wherefores of this configuration are no longer avilable, and neither is the original admin.

What we want to accomplish here is to move the records for EXAMPLE.NET to a Windows DNS server used for other purposes in the organization, and cause minimal interruption and reconfiguration to the rest of the infra. This port 5353 EXAMPLE.NET is in innumerable configuration files all over the place, and tracking these all down will take quite a while.

To that end, we've copied the zone data from the BIND server onto the Windows server. I would now like to  make EXAMPLE.NET on the BIND server a slave of the Microsoft DNS server.

### Configuration & the problem

I've configured everything such that the BIND server can manually transfer the zones from the Microsoft server, but I'd like to use notifications instead. The zone properties window in the DNS management snap-in has a place to add servers to be notified on zone updates, **but it does not allow setting of a port**, coming back with a `The string entered is neither a valid IP address nor a valid DNS name` message, when using either `host:port` or `host#port` notation.

Short of some horrid hack involving iptables on the BIND server, I need to know if it is possible to have a Microsoft DNS server send zone updates to a DNS server running on a nonstandard port?

*Please note: I am very interested in the answer to this specific question, and not very interested in other ways this goal could be achieved, say, by using views and running DNS on the standard port*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noticed Windows DNS server only allows settings IP addresses in the list of servers to be notified. That's pretty much dead end. (Frankly, at first the question sounded like a bad idea, but as the goal is to enable gradual transition towards better practices, it's really a good question.)

In BIND, you don't need use any more complex features like the views you have mentioned. You can simply make BIND available on both ports, `53` and `5353`, simultaneously:

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    listen-on port 5353 { any; };
}
```

This will allow the legacy systems use port `5353` while the Windows Server notifies over `53`. Also, it enables you to get rid of the *horrid iptables hack* solution currently used for changing the DNS port.